# Exposing a file system as an Amazon S3 compatible service

Tags: open-source, cloud-storage, amazon

I am looking for open source software that can be used for expose a file system tree as a service with an S3 (subset) compatible API.

I need something that allows software (i.e. GenomeSpace which has has S3 client capability) to remotely read and write files from the file system of my server *as if* my server was a full-blown S3 server.

Redundancy, etcetera is not a requirement.  This is not full-function Object Storage: it is simply making files and directories *look like* object storage to an S3 client running on another machine (probably in the same data centre).

I should have mentioned that my server will run some flavour of Linux.

Comment: Might be useful to add some more details: if "software" (ready-to-use), what OS? If library (which I take from your mentioning "compatible API"), what programming language?

Comment: Internet Archive has a S3 interface, maybe you can borrow some of their code (much of it is in GitHub).

Comment: I haven't actually used this but you might try: http://s3ninja.net/ It sets up an S3 API for development and testing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a private S3-like service atop your data / file system, then you need a software stack such as [Eucalyptus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eucalyptus_(software)) that implements an AWS-alike set of services atop your private infrastructure.

The specific Eucalyptus component you'd need is called "Walrus."

Answer (score -1):

You can try [s3fs](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) for Linux, or possibly [wins3fs](https://wins3fs.codeplex.com) for Windows (though its last update is forever old).

There are also commercial alternatives like [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/expandrive), but these fail your "open source" criteria.

I would caution you to test whatever solution you pick rather carefully. I have used both open and proprietary approaches to "S3 as a file system," and have never been satisfied with their reliability. Trying to couple what fundamentally is a remote, high-latency resource with a software system (the file system) that expects a very local, low-latency resource--well, the two often don't match up very well. I've found that I can copy files beautifully to and from S3...and then a few minutes later, when I try to copy more files, the connection is somehow broken. This is an an environment with 50 Mbps network connections, in which software like `ssh` and `scp` have no problems whatever.  My experience is that trying to treat S3 as a file system seemed like the very simplest and most fool-proof approach...but in practice, it often did not work robustly, and I spent more time restarting my S3 file system connection than it was worth. I have since switched to command-line tools like `s3cmd` which do not suffer the same drop-outs. YMMV.

Comment: You have misunderstood my requirements. I don't want to make S3 look like a file system. I want to make a file system look like S3